# execute python script from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I am a newbie to python. I am working on a web app and trying to call a python script from a js script. I am using ajax to call the .py script as follows but I just keep getting the code returned in the response. For simplicity, I have reduced the computation in the python script - even the variable x is not being returned to the js file.

in js function

```
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'test.py',

    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
      return console.error(response);
    }
  });
```

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print("Hello World")

x = 2
return x
```

The request succeeds because it moves inside success. response is the python code instead of 2.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

You have to use a so called application server to serve HTTP requests in Python. Look at this [one](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) or try to use some lightweight web frameworks like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org).

The simplest web application in the Flask will look like this (in example, put it to `app.py` file):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test.py")  # consider to use more elegant URL in your JS
def get_x():
    x = 2
    return x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # here is starting of the development HTTP server
    app.run()
```

Then you must start your server by doing:

```
python app.py
```

By default it'll start on `localhost:3000`. Hence, you have to change `url` in the JS code to `http://localhost:3000/test.py`.

**UPD:** Also note that the listed web servers are not production-ready. To build the production-ready configuration you can use something like [uWSGI+nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-python-wsgi-applications-using-uwsgi-web-server-with-nginx) binding.